# Java not compiling my source code

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I am unable to compile my class in command line. I must be missing something very obvious but I can't figure it out.

Here my settings...

Environment settings (Win 8.1):

```
JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11

Path    %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

I have "javaTest" folder containing two java files Run.java and Animal.java.
I can compile Animal.java but I get an error compiling the "Run.java" file.

Command line:

```
C:\>cd C:\javaTest

C:\javaTest>dir
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk

Directory of C:\javaTest

01/10/2014  10:37 AM    <DIR>          .
01/10/2014  10:37 AM    <DIR>          ..
01/10/2014  10:37 AM               337 Animal.java
01/10/2014  10:36 AM               230 Run.java
               2 File(s)            567 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  42,796,736,512 bytes free

C:\javaTest>javac Animal.java (**note: this gets executed without problems**)

C:\javaTest>javac Run.java
Run.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                Animal a1 = new Animal();
                ^
  symbol:   class Animal
  location: class Run
Run.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                Animal a1 = new Animal();
                                ^
  symbol:   class Animal
  location: class Run
Run.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Animal a2 = new Animal("Animal2");
                ^
  symbol:   class Animal
  location: class Run
Run.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Animal a2 = new Animal("Animal2");
                                ^
  symbol:   class Animal
  location: class Run
4 errors
```

Here is the actual code:

Run.java

```
    public class Run{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            Animal a1 = new Animal();
            a1.setName("Animal1");
            a1.showName();

            Animal a2 = new Animal("Animal2");      
            System.out.println(a2.getName());

        }

    }
```

Animal.java

```
    public class Animal{

        private String name;

        public Animal() {

        }
        public Animal(String name) {
            this.name = name;

        }

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return this.name;       
        }


        public void showName(){
            System.out.println(this.name);      
        }

    }
```

I can run the very same code from Eclipse without any problems. So I am not sure what I am missing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the actual folder to the classpath:

```
javac -cp .\;%CLASSPATH% Animal.java
```

Comment: Weird that this is needed. Do you have a CLASSPATH environmental variable at all? By default java/javac should be using the current working directory (".") as the classpath if none is specified. If you have a CLASSPATH environmental variable then removing it may make your learner life easier.

Comment: I do have Classpath set up in my environment variables pointing to several locations. However my classpath did not include "." which I assume was the issue. That's really the only thing that I have changed and I was able to compile afterwards.